# Pandas trying to transform a dataframe by getting rows between certain strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset that looks something like this:

| COL1 | COL2 |
| --- | --- |
| name | name_2 |
| a | 1 |
| b | 2 |
| stop | stop |
| name2 | name2_2 |
| c | 3 |
| d | 4 |
| e | 5 |
| stop | stop |

I want to transform it to something like:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| name | a | 1 |
| name | b | 1 |
| name2 | c | 3 |
| name2 | d | 4 |
| name2 | e | 5 |

I've been trying to find a way to subset the dataset to get everything between "name" and "Stop"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to transform:

```
d = {'COL1': {0: 'name', 1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'stop', 4: 'name2', 5: 'c', 6: 'd', 7: 'e', 8: 'stop'}, 'COL2': {0: 'name_2', 1: '1', 2: '2', 3: 'stop', 4: 'name2_2', 5: '3', 6: '4', 7: '5', 8: 'stop'}}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
m = df.COL1.str.contains('name')
df.loc[m, 't'] = df.loc[m]['COL1']
df = df.fillna(method= 'ffill')
df = df.groupby('t').apply(lambda x : x.iloc[1:-1]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Rename/sort columns :

```
df.columns = ['COL2','COL3','COL1']
df = df[sorted(df.columns)]
```

OUTPUT:

```
    COL1 COL2 COL3
0   name    a    1
1   name    b    2
2  name2    c    3
3  name2    d    4
4  name2    e    5
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but that np import is unnecessary. +1 either way.